# How to capture session information from PHP in ASP?

Tags: php, asp.net, session, single-sign-on

I'm working in a website that is going to work like a landing point, providing a specialized service for many other websites. Users log-in to different sites and those sites have links to my website.

Now, I want to create my website using asp .net, and also I want to be able to use SSO (Single Sign-On) so the users doesn't have to authenticate again when they land on my site.

The problem is that most of the websites that are going to use the services of my site are in php, when users login on these sites, all the authentication process is handled and also a lot of data is fetched into the Session variable; what I want to do is to be able to capture all the data in the session variable coming from the php page, in my asp site.

I don't know if this is possible, maybe this can be done in another way

So far, the only thing I've been able to do in the asp is, ask for a parameter in the url and using that parameter query the database to get all the data that was already in the session in php.

So if any of you know a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My company does this extensively.  Our app passes information from our software to other systems such as CRM's, appointment schedulers, data aggregators, etc.  In cases where systems are radically different and access is not explicitly given, the best solution we've found is to use cURL and negotiate a data interchange via API.  Setups with people of varying technical abilities can be challenging (we've actually provided code for several systems we wanted to communicate with) but in the end it's efficient and secure.

Unlike many UI guys, I'm a fan of OpenID for single login.  However, that doesn't pass all the data you likely want to interchange between the sites.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a database as a session store point accessible by all pages. this makes it pretty easy to access session data by either php or asp.

I think this would be the mos performant way.

If you don'T want to give the other php sites any access to your databases you also could create a special page not for vewing in asp and tell the php sites to drop the session contents via curl there and in that sie then save the session stuff in your database.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you are hosting both ASP and PHP websites on one server or if your ASP site will be used with other third-party sites.

If you run and manage the ASP and PHP sites on one machine, then storing session information in the database will be the way to go and isn't too difficult. You'll need to make sure that the session data you store in the database can be read by both PHP and ASP--I'd pick something simple like JSON. A url parameter would be a bad way to get at this data, as it makes user information available to anyone who could guess a user id.

It's not so simple, however, if you want to provide SSO capabilities with third party sites. In this case, you'll have to implement an authentication API that the third party sites can call to log their user into your site when they initially authenticate the user on their own.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that part, the ASP site will be used by third-party sites. Let me ask you, aside from the user credentials, is there another way, besides the database approach, to obtain the data from the session in the ASP site?

Comment: You'll want to develop an authentication api such as one described by bpeterson76 below that can pass around the data you want to share. OpenID might be a good fit for this situation and maybe OAuth would be worth looking at too as there are plenty of OAuth libraries you can choose from.